# concert ways to improve loading time in Android WebView

Tags: performance, android-webview

I am trying all means to improve the loading time of an link in android webview in vain.I am using a link which has images and text fetched from external server by using some js functions and those images and text may change on any moment.In this scenario the code I used is as below.I am not interested in HTML 5 caching or server caching techniques,as the same link loads faster on browser fails to do the same in android webview.There is not much js script i can load from resource to improve performance hence most of the script just pulls data from external server and images from on amazon server.

```
    WebSettings settings = getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    settings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(false);
    settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    settings.setGeolocationEnabled(false);
```

1 .I guess turning on DomStaorage and AppCache to true have impact on loading time so i have turned it off. -> Is this true

2.In OnDestroy i call clearcache on webview to clear application cache - I am doing this hence i am afraid that my app size may grow as webview db grows if i fail to clear.-> is this must,or android handles this gracefully.

3.Few suggestion i hear is to set setCacheMode to LOAD_NO_CACHE and comment clearing webview cache in onDestroy. --> Does calling webview.clearcache() have any impact hence I have already set not to load from cache.

4.The link does not provide me information of previously refreshed time,in that case what cache mode could any one recommend.

5.Is there is any concert testing method to find out loading time on devices that takes network connection and server lags into account.hence the same page once it loads fast may load slow in some other time.

Comment: You have to wait like 500ms for each html link ?

Comment: I suppose , is there is any better way to load the link faster?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with "[fast click](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)".

> mobile browsers will wait approximately 300ms from the time that you tap the button to fire the click event. The reason for this is that the browser is waiting to see if you are actually performing a double tap.

Download the script, add

```
<script type='application/javascript' src='fastclick.js'></script>
```

in your header and this code in your script.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
}, false);
```

---

More informations: https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons

Comment: This doesn't work for me ,can someone clarify me the 5 points that i have queried